# The meaning of "spat out" in the mentioned sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "spat out" in the following sentence?

> And in Titelbaum and Kopec’s Reasoning Room, one agent knows that her
>   reasoning process **spat out** P while the other knows that her reasoning
>   process **spat out** not P. ([Source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwix6a31k6jYAhVMq48KHR70DbQQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fsite%2Fmichaeltitelbaum%2Fresearch%2FKopecTitelbaumUniquenessOffprint.pdf&usg=AOvVaw357pxIe4khkz7sfwX0LwwH))

"spat out" is the past form of "spit out". But here "spat out" seems not to be a past form.

Comment: This is an ***indirect metaphor relating to early computers with punch cards***. The cards would come flying out of the machine. The machine was said to spit them out. To spit out means to produce very quickly.  To produce automatically. spit, spat, spat are the parts of the verbs.

Comment: Do you have evidence for this, @Lambie? It seems unlikely to me, because, first, the result of a calculation us usually displayed or printed rather than output on cards, and secondly, when I have seen cards emerging from a card-punch, they don't come flying out individually, but as a stack in a hopper. To me the metaphor seems more likely to refer to a machine manufacturing smallish objects that get ejected into a bin at the end.

Comment: To spit out anything just means that it do it quickly. I was merely addressing a likely origin. No, I obviously cannot "prove it". There are old films that show cards tumbling out of machines; not going into the hopper, Falling all over the floor. As this is reasoning, and computers "reason" with the logic fed into them, that was my idea  here. Not objects per se.

Comment: spat out is most definitely the past form: the simple past.

Comment: As a side note, this is a really interesting paper.

Comment: @Colin - I agree with you, I'm not so sure that punch cards are a "likely origin", but I'd agree that "the machine started spitting punch cards" would be a figurative use similar to the O.P.'s quote. I've also heard of slot machines spitting out quarters, and the OED has (under a definition reading "To emit, cast, throw, in a manner similar to the ejection of saliva") a 1911 quote:  _The bullets came crashing through the cactus leaves, spitting up sand all around us_

Answer (score 1):

It is a past form: the reasoning process has already given its answer. It could equally have been perfect (*has spat out P*).

Comment: That is actually why I think it should have been "has spat out p" in this example if it was the past form of spit out.

Comment: There are very few cases where a present perfect cannot be replaced by a simple past (the reverse is not true). I would find the perfect more natural here, but the past is certainly possible.

Comment: Here, they are describing a single past occurrence, spat out is right, and has spat out would be a mistake here in this text. It's a one-off thing.

Comment: It depends on context, @Lambie. I haven't looked at the original paper, but the excerpt given could easily mean that they are still holding or contemplating the results of the process, in which case it is _past event with present relevance_ and the perfect will be justified.

Comment: @Colin Fine Well, perhaps you might take a look at the  paper then. As this approximates logic, I'd go with simple past in this case.

Comment: Okay, @Lambie, I have looked at the paper.  I still think that _has spat_ is just as good as _spat_ in that context. It is completely unspecified whether the consideration described is just after the Reasoning Room has operated, or much later.